# Optimzing this SQL query

Tags: sql

This takes about 2h to load and it's too large for me to use it in my BI tool. The culprit is `huge_table`. I've added a date partition (ds) to huge_table but it still takes really long to load. Please help me optimize the query below:

```
        WITH huge.table AS (
             SELECT distinct ORDER_ID, account_id, ds
             FROM "huge.table"
             WHERE yesno_condition='y'   AND days_active>0 )
         
         , CTE2 AS (   SELECT CTE2.EMAIL, CTE2.CONTACT_ID   FROM
         Contact_details_table   JOIN huge.table HT ON
         (CTE2.ORDER_ID=HT.ORDER_ID AND CTE2.account_id=HT.account_id)   Where
         CTE2.EMAIL IN (SELECT NEW_EMAIL as EMAIL FROM maintable
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT EMAIL as EMAIL FROM maintable)
             AND HT.ds>= dateadd(year, -2, current_date) 
         
         SELECT  
        mt.metric1, 
        mt.metric2, 
        mt.metric3, 
        mt.metric4, 
        mt.metric5,
        mt.metric6, 
        mt.metric7, 
        mt.metric8, 
        mt.metric9, 
        mt.metric10,
        mt.metric11, 
        mt.metric12, 
        mt.metric13, 
        mt.metric14, 
        ot.metric1,
        CTE2.CONTACT_ID 
 
      FROM  maintable as L 
      JOIN CTE2 U ON lower(CTE2.EMAIL)=(case when (mt.EMAIL !=CTE2.EMAIL) then NEW_EMAIL END) 
      JOIN othertable AS ot ON (mt.old_email=ot.email OR mt.new_email=ot.email) 
WHERE ot.exist_condition='Y'  
AND ot.ACCOUNT_TYPE !='inactive' 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
```

Comment: MySQL or Snowflake? Choose the right tag. `SELECT DISTINCT` on a huge table is a slow operation - can you keep that table optimized with a MATERIALIZED VIEW instead?

Comment: @devlincarnate No, that's not the criteria for what belongs on Code Review. Please do not suggest sites whose scope you are unfamiliar with, and, more importantly, do not turn away questions that are on-topic where they were asked (like this one is). Specific, targeted optimization questions are perfectly fine for Stack Overflow, and they're not opinion-based.

Comment: Your join against CTE2  is not sargable. If the data is very large, can you make use of a temp table instead with appropriate indexes?

Comment: @CodyGray -umm, Code Review does specifically state that requests for optimization are on topic.  That is NOT listed as being on topic for Stack Overflow.  Moreover, there are plenty of topics on Stack Exchange that state that working code is generally better suited for CR versus SO.  I am not off base in my suggestion -- this is not a targeted request.  It's a "this take a long time, please help me" which at best, is a grey area.  It certainly doesn't warrant my comment being deleted based on your opinion (diamond or not)

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest issue here is the union all and these subselects. In general I would try to lower burden by making smaller temporary tables. If you have one huge table make it compact step by step. ¨

Try how long will take to execute only for example this part of the query

```
SELECT CTE2.EMAIL, CTE2.CONTACT_ID   FROM
         Contact_details_table   JOIN huge.table HT ON
         (CTE2.ORDER_ID=HT.ORDER_ID AND CTE2.account_id=HT.account_id)   Where
         CTE2.EMAIL IN (SELECT NEW_EMAIL as EMAIL FROM maintable
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT EMAIL as EMAIL FROM maintable)
             AND HT.ds>= dateadd(year, -2, current_date)
```

If this takes forever make it into one or two separate temporary tables before working with it.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply! This CTE2 is joining CTE1(=huge table). I need to join CTE1 because I want to overlap of order_ids between cte1 and cte2. Can you explain how I can separate this out even more?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is huge and you are attempting to surround it with a CTE then you will lose all indexes and statistics and it will become a heap. How big is your table? If it is huge, then you could gain traction by declaring a #table and inserting the data and then add appropriate indexes. Then do your query, it is worth a try out.